# Read FileStreamResult API response and return it as FileContentResult C# .Net 6

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, filestreamresult

I have an API which gets data from another API. This endpoint returns a "FileStreamResult" as the response. I need to read this response content from the other API and return it as "FileContentResult". How could I achieve this?

Endpoint - API 01

```
[HttpGet("user/{email}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetImage(string email)
{
    var image = await _imageService.GetImageAsync(fileName);

    return image == null
        ? NotFound()
        : File(image.FileStream, image.ContentType);
}
```

Reading data - API 02

```
var endPoint = $"/api/image/user/{email}";
var response = await _client.GetAsync(new Uri(endPoint, UriKind.Relative)).ConfigureAwait(false);

var data = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(); //This is how I thought to do it but this might be wrong
```

I get the correct response from the endpoint but I need to read the content and return it as a "filecontentResult".

Comment: Wouldn't it just be a difference of using the File() helper with a string instead of a stream?

Comment: "I need to read the content and return it as a "filecontentStream"" return it where? What do you need to return, what format? A string, a stream of bytes, something else?

Comment: @Devon I need to read the stream and return it as "filecontentResult"

Comment: @Charlieface Response gives an image file as a "FileStreamResult" I need to transform it to "filecontentStream".

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `data` is just a `Stream`, that will work anywhere you need a stream. What class is `FileContentStream` and why do you need it?

Comment: @Hash_Dew you need to use a stream reader and assign the result to a string.  Research "how to read a stream into a string"